# Scrolling QTableView in QVBoxLayout in QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qscrollarea, qvboxlayout

I had a problem with QTableView widget:
I need to horizontal scroll whole widget with headers, but standart scrolling scroll only content, but not headers.

Then I tried to add QScrollArea like this (this all in QDockWidget):

```
class matrix : public QScrollArea {
};
```

in constructor:

```
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

tableView = new QTableView(this);
tableView->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
tableView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
layout->addWidget(tableView);

this->setLayout(layout);
```

but it doesn't work properly: scrolling bar doesn't appear.

(sorry, if I break some rules - it's my first question here, and sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What happens, if you attach the layout to the viewport, assuming there is one set? Like `QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(viewport());`

Comment: I'm a newbie in Qt and may be I don't understand you properly, but i tried this - no difference.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer, because it includes too much code for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could for instance remove the layout and set the `QTableView` directly as viewport.

```
tableView = new QTableView;
setWidget(tableView);
setWidgetResizable(true);
tableView->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
tableView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work (no difference)